# Why does Windows show 'speakers' even when headphones are connected?

Tags: audio, drivers, digital-audio

[image]

^^When this screenshot was taken, headphones were connected and music was playing through them... :|

**Details**:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Mine says "speaker and headphones" when headset is connected because it is a laptop and only has headphone port...I guess it depends on type of sound card/available ports and drivers installed for it what will show, post more info about your sound hardware.

Comment: I've yet to find a pair of headphones that didn't contain speakers ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill The only way the OS would know they are headphones is by what port on the sound card they are plugged into. This is why the poster needs to add more info about the sound card.

Comment: @Moab Perhaps you missed the smiley? :/

Comment: @DavidPostill :D

Comment: @DavidPostill nope, I upvoted your comment, my first good laugh of the day, thanks. I made the comment hoping Rahul would edit his question with new information we need.

Comment: @Moab Anything else??

Comment: Why the downvotes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text says "speakers" because that's how Realtek High Definition Audio registers itself. Realtek is apparently responsible for the headphones port, so the device plugged in there gets called whatever they say. (It is my understanding that devices plugged into those ports do not identify themselves by brand/model/form-factor.)

**Related: "why doesn't it show a different icon if I have dual headphones (output with mic)?"**

The volume control displays a speaker icon, not a combined speaker/microphone icon, because that slider only controls output volume. To see this, open Sound and highlight your default device.

[image: sound]

Click Properties, then switch to the Levels tab. Notice how the top slider has the same value as the taskbar volume control.

[image: levels tab]

Back in Sound, switch to the Recording tab. Do the same thing, opening your selected device's properties and looking at the Levels tab.

[image: microphone levels]

Notice how this value is independent from your output volume.

Comment: Thanks!! It seems to be the same for the S/PDIF port.. :(